# Jquery image slider previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML code**
i am creating jquery image slider and this html and css code for that image slider.

```
<style type="text/css">
#slider{overflow: hidden; width: 600px; height: 400px; position: relative; border: 4px solid #CCC; margin: auto;}
#slider ul{padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 2400px; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;}
#slider ul li{list-style: none; float: left;}
#slider ul li img{width: 600px; height: 400px;}
.next{position: relative; left: 700px; }
.prev{position: relative; left: 500px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="4.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="5.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<button class="prev">prev</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS code**
This is jquery code for image slider in which next button working properly but i tried to create prev button code but didn't get success.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var count = $("#slider ul li").length;
            var li_w = $("#slider ul li:first").width();
            var ul_w = count*li_w;
            var i = li_w;
            $(".next").click(function(){
                $("#slider ul").animate({"left":-i+"px"}, 1000);
                i+= li_w;
                if(i==ul_w){
                    i=0;
                }
            });

            $(".prev").click(function(){

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Check this reference link this will help you..[click](http://www.uiupdates.com/create-circular-image-gallery-using-jquery/)

Comment: WOW.. thanx exactly what i want .appreciated men

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your javascript a bit but I think its more logical like this.
Here you can try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/vkk52bz2/2/

```
$(function(){
    var count = $("#slider ul li").length;
    var li_w = $("#slider ul li:first").width();
    var ul_w = count*li_w;
    var i = 0; // start with the position 0
    $(".next").click(function(){
        i -= li_w; // subtract the width of a slide
        if(i==ul_w*-1){ // check if it hit the end
            i=0;
        }
        $("#slider ul").animate({"left":i+"px"}, 1000);
    });

    $(".prev").click(function(){
        i += li_w; // add the width of a slide
        if(i>0){ // check if it hit end
            i= ((count-1) * li_w) * -1;
        }
        $("#slider ul").animate({"left":i+"px"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx for your help but prev button still not working properly

Comment: @GauravKumar oh sorry.. i should have tested it first. i updated the post

Comment: i Appreciate you help thanx gonna use this code because it easiest...thank you

Answer (score 0):

***I tested it and it works*** 
https://jsfiddle.net/thair/s8hhz415/2/embedded/result/

> html

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/31.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/27.JPG" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/23.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://kelmih.com/Photos/News/24.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<button class="prev">prev</button>
```

> css

```
#slider{overflow: hidden; width: 600px; height: 400px; position: relative; border: 4px solid #CCC; margin: auto;}
#slider ul{padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 2400px; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;}
#slider ul li{list-style: none; float: left;}
#slider ul li img{width: 600px; height: 400px;}
.next{position: relative; left: 100px; }
.prev{position: relative; left: 0px; }
```

> JS

```
             $(function(){
                var count = $("#slider ul li").length;
                var li_w = $("#slider ul li:first").width();
                var ul_w = count*li_w;
                var i = 0;
                $(".next").click(function(){
                    i+= li_w;
                     if(i>ul_w || i==ul_w){
                        i=0;
                    }
                    $("#slider ul").animate({"left":-i+"px"}, 1000);
                });
                $(".prev").click(function(){
                    i-= li_w;
                    if(i<0 ){
                        i=ul_w - li_w;
                    }
                    $("#slider ul").animate({"left":-i+"px"}, 1000);
                });
            });
```

Comment: it is not working when i click to next and then i click to prev button then it keep decreasing the li_w but thanx for the help